# Database replication or others concepts?

Tags: database, replication, distributed

I'm new in database replication and distributed database topics. I have a desktop system that use a PostgreSQL database.

This system is focused to manage some process in one Entity or Enterprise. Now appear other business model. Now there is many entities and one of them controls the others. So, it's mandatory that the Controller Entity manages the information of all children entities. Each entity has its own database server and must tribute information to the controller entity server.

The flow of information must be bidirectional, so each action over the controller database must be reflected in one o more entities databases.Each action over one entity database must be reflected in controller database.[image]

So, if someone know a database replication program that can help me, just tell me about that. Windows or Unix. If the program offer a UI to configure the replication process, then better for me.

Comment: Are the database servers (computers) all located at the same location?

Comment: Yes, databases are running in different servers (computers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning same this flow.I think you can do data integration process. If your database is MSSQL you can use "SSIS" and also database replication but if database more than 1 or 2 sql server i think process will slow.Please see my suggestion below. If you have other experiences now please let me know. Thanks you

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ikNnenDyNw][1]

Comment: Please do not rely on links for the bulk of the content for your answer. Links can go dead, or content can change. You can edit your answer to include a summary or explanation of what the content in your link, but the external resource should be supplementary only.